# Generated file with protobuf-net for c# is different a little from the same file generated in C++

Tags: c#, file, binary, protobuf-net, winmerge

I'm having a wired issue, I'm using protobuf-net for C# to generate a file which based on Google Protocol Buffer message and then upload it to one of my company's servers.

I created a tool in C# that generates a .proto file to .cs, then I'm using its classes (from .cs file) to fill all the required fields in the message and after that I called to Serializer.Serialze() function and its creates for me the requested file.

BUT, and this is the problem, I have another file (same file) which created in another tool that wrote in C++ (uses the same .proto file that I used), but when I'm trying to upload my file to our servers I'm getting an error that something is wrong.

I compared the 2 files with "Win Merge" software and I noticed a very little differences in 3 different lines (out of 7000+ lines in each file) compared to the file that generated in the C++ tool.

Here is example of 2 line captured from Win Merge tool (on the Left the C++, on the right C#):

[image]

[image: Another example:]

I notice that the differences is in the rectangulars (which I don't understand what is there meaning) with the bytes inside them...

Here is the .proto file that I'm using:

```
message Package {

message ArchDepend {

    message Arch {
        required string version = 1;
        required string description = 2;
    }

    message Firmware {
        required string version = 1;
        required string description = 2;
        required bytes file = 3;

        repeated string from_version = 4;
    }

    message Rsu {
        required string version = 1;
        required string description = 2;
        required bytes file = 3;
    }

    required Arch arch = 1;

    optional Firmware firmware = 2;
    optional Rsu rsu = 3;
}

message DefaultEeprom {
    required string version = 1;
    required string description = 2;
    required bytes file = 3;

    message Migration {
        required string from_version = 1;
        required bytes file = 2;
    }

    repeated Migration migrations = 4;
}

required string name = 1;
optional ArchDepend archDepend = 2;
optional DefaultEeprom defaultEeprom = 3;
```

}

The fields that I'm insert in the .cs file are strings and files(*.bin) here is example for the strings:

"PowerMaster-30"

"JS702394 K17.A20"

etc..

They are inserted to most of the strings fields in the .proto file.

In the files fields (.proto) I'm loading a binary files that my company uses (the same files which loaded to the C++ tool).

Here is a screen shot of the binary file which I'm reading data from, opened in program called "Falsher.exe", in the left is converted to Hex view, in the right is the ASCII:

[image]

And here is the code that reading that binary file:

```
       private string[] FindPanelVersionInBinFile(string path)
    {
        string currentline;
        int flag = 0;
        string[] namesArray = new string[3]; // contains all the strings which I get from the BIN file.

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            while ((currentline = sr.ReadLine()) != null && flag < 3)
            {
                if (currentline.Contains("PRODUCT_FAMILY"))
                {
                    int index = currentline.IndexOf("PRODUCT_FAMILY");
                    namesArray[0] = currentline.Substring(index + 16, 14); // index of product family"PowerMaster-xx"
                    flag++;
                }
                if (currentline.Contains("SW_VERSION"))
                {
                    int index = currentline.IndexOf("SW_VERSION");
                    namesArray[1] = currentline.Substring(index + 12, 17); // index of software version "JSxxxxx Kxx.yyy"
                    flag++;                       
                }
                if (currentline.Contains("compatibility"))
                {
                    int index = currentline.IndexOf("compatibility");
                    namesArray[2] = currentline.Substring(index + 21, 7); // index of compatibility number "xx.yyy"
                    flag++;
                }                  
            }
        }
        return namesArray;
```

After all that, I'm using this code to generates my file:

```
                        byte[] data;
                        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            Serializer.Serialize(ms, package);
                            data = ms.ToArray();
                        }
                        string packageFilePath = Path.Combine(savePath, package.Name);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(packageFilePath, data);
```

Someone can help me please to explain to me what is exactly the differences and from what reason they happened?

Thank you!!

Orion.

Comment: by the way, the rectangulars are just telling you that this is a non-printable character, i.e. the `[10]` is a byte with value (in hex, I suspect) of `10`, i.e. a byte with value `16` in human terms. You can't really represent that as text (on most maps it would be the "data link escape" character, "DLE") - but that isn't important here because that data *is not text in any way*.

Comment: btw, in the bottom screen-shot, your text data is simply different: on the left it is clearly `"JS702394 K17.A20 same"`; on the right it is `"JS702394 K17.A20"` - this time without a nul-terminator, but the difference is the `" same"`. I have no idea where the `" same"` came from, but I strongly suspect it is in your code, or your source data (protobuf-net doesn't routinely go around appending random strings)

Comment: Re your edit, I am geuninely surprised to hear that the version on the right is the C# version, but I don't think that changes anything - it is still getting that `\0` (nul-terminator) from somewhere: I suspect from your code - you need to check your code to see where that came from. In particular, check whether `yourString[yourString.Length - 1] == (char)0`.

Comment: do I really have to code that hex in by hand? any chance you could just upload it or email it to me? or copy the *hex* in here as text? I'll happily verify your `FindPanelVersionInBinFile` method - but I *really* don't want to type that lot in manually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It *looks* like the difference is simply zero-terminated strings.

I'm guessing (please correct me) that the data on the left is from protobuf-net, and the data on the right is from the C++ implementation. On the left we have `" [10]`, some data, and then `[1A]` (I *believe* the `[1A]` is the next field-header: field 3, length-prefixed). Supporting this hypothesis, the "character" (loosely speaking) *before* the `[10]`/`[11]` is `"`, i.e. ASCII 34 - which is (in protobuf) means "field 2, length-prefixed". So I'm content to say that the `" [10]` is telling us "field 2, string of length 16", and the `" [11]` is telling us "field 2, string of length 17".

As such, it feels logical that the string in C# is `"JS702415 K17.020"`, and the string in C++ is the same but *with a nul-terminator*. Here is gets interesting: I do not believe that it should be including the nul-terminator. So: either the C++ API is making a mistake (which I doubt), or when passing the data to C++ you are accidentally *telling* it to (incorrectly) include the nul-terminator to the string.

I'm sure that the encoding is not meant to include nul-terminators, because the [protocol specification](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) gives the example of the string "testing" (as field 2), which it encodes as:

```
12 07 74 65 73 74 69 6e 67
```

the `12` is the field-header (field 2, length-prefixed); the `07` is the length, and the next 7 bytes (`74`...`67`) is the payload, UTF-8 encoded. Note: no nul-terminator.

Comment: Thank you @Marc
The data from the left is C++ and on the right is the C#.
I edited my question and add more useful information to review.

Comment: @Orionlk the interesting piece now is: what code are you using to tell the C++ API your strings? In particular, the strings of the form `"JS702415 K17.020"`. I suspect that you simply have a bug in that line, and you are telling the builder API to include one too many characters. An off-by-one-error in your code.

Comment: the C++ tool wrote (not my me) in Qt GUI and the parameters there are taken from TextBoxs fields, is the same like my tool - I'm reading these string from inside a binary file, using StreamReader and serach line line after my desire string, and copying it to a textBox and then to my google message parameter.

Comment: @Orionlk I've checked protobuf-net, and *if you **give it** a string with a nul-terminator* (very uncommon in .NET), it preserves the nul-terminator during serialization and deserialization. So: I have to conclude that in your "left" code you are giving it a string *without* a nul-terminator, and in your "right"code you are giving it a string *with* a nul-terminator. If you give each side different data: then yes, they will serialize differently. You need to investigate why you have different data on the two sides (in particular, why one version of your code is including the...

Comment: @Orionlk ...nul-terminator, and where the `" same"` came from). As far as I can see, it looks like both serializers are doing fine - but simply you are giving them ever-so-slightly differently data to work with.

Comment: I'm reading these string from inside of a binary file, then uses myString = string.substring(x,y) function to cut the relevant bytes from the line to myString, and copy the content to .proto relevant field. Maybe I should to convert myString to UTF-8 encoded or something?

Comment: @Orionlk I would look very carefully at that bit of code, indeed. It sounds very likely to be the culprit. Any chance you can show **exactly** how you are reading it?

Comment: @Marc_Gravell first of all thank you for your help! I've edited my original question and add to it some more information - ScreenShot and the function which reads the Bin file

Comment: @Marc_Gravell its now working!! I indeed read 1 more additional byte which was unnecessary. Thank you!